Man riding a cannonball and escape from prison (black and white flick)
I saw this movie on TV about 18 years ago, it is really old (probably 1950 or older), the movie is not very serious and does not have much logic. Cannot remember most of the scenes, but this one's stuck in my mind: lots of things would happen, probably a battle would have started, and this guy's cell would be hit and he would be travelling on the bomb (a cannonball). Any idea what it is?

Perhaps you mean this iconic scene from
Stanley Kubrick's Dr. Strangelove (1964)?

no no, not that awesome movie, this is set in a different era, also not that serious, bit on the comedic edge if i remember correctly i.e not too much logic

OK. Perhaps could you elaborate a little, then: What year is the movie likely from and what year does the plot take place in? Is it in English? Is it animated or live action? Does the guy ride a bomb in order to escape prison (not really clear about this point)? What did the bomb look like?

"Travelling on the bomb"? I just can't imagine. The one that hit the cell and did not explode? But it is not moving?

that's the problem i do not remember much, it is really old film, proabably 1950 - or older, the movie does not have much logic( obviously doesnot bother much with physics, when it lets hero ride cannonball), the bomb is a cannon ball...

Hmm, could be one of the films about Baron Münchhausen.

u are talking about the one staring uma truman, i have seen it, but it is not that one.

There were several films about him, I'm just not sure which ones were in B&W. Anyway, added the info.

thanks @Walt i think it is this one , en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Münchhausen_(film)

@mido22 Glad to hear. You can answer your own question and approve it.

it was the 1943 version i was looking for, the Münchhausen
